# Combinatorics: Understanding proofs involving the bijective principle(BP)

Tags: combinatorics, proof-theory

When we are trying to prove a statement using the bijective principle, it is clear that the goal is show that two sets are equivalent in cardinality. The following proof of example 1.5.3 starts with two sets A and B where A resembles the set from the proposition and set B contains r-combinations of Y, where the cardinality of Y will be n-r+1 choose r. So it seems we want to relate sets A and B by some bijective function, hence showing that |A| = |B|. It then follows that |A| is equal to n-r+1 choose r.

I believe I have a good understanding of this proof, however the action of creating a function for the proof seems strange. Some questions I have are:

1. If we were unable to find a function that relates these two sets bijectively, then does it follow that the proposition must be false?
2. Is there more than one possible way to create a bijective function within a proof?
3. Is the creation of the function that maps A to B (whether it be bijective, injective or surjective depending on what you are proving) that is really the key to the proof? In general, are there instances were two seemingly unrelated sets can be connected by the creation of some mapping function and then used to prove some proposition?

[image: From Techniques and Principles in Combinatorics]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, being unable to find it never proves the nonexistence of it. However, if you can *prove* there does not exist a bijection, then you can prove that the two sets have different cardinality.
2. Yes, unless you're dealing with sets of size $0$ or $1$, you can find a different bijection simply by swapping two values around. For example, if $x\neq x'$ and $f(x)=y$ and $f(x')=y'$, then the function $g$ such that $g(x)=y'$ and $g(x')=y$ and $g(z)=f(z)$ for all $z\neq x,x'$ is also a bijection.
3. It is, since cardinality is *defined* in terms of function mappings: $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality $|A|=|B|$, when there exists a bijection $A\to B$. There is however an easier way to show equality of cardinality: if we have injective functions $A\to B$ and $B\to A$, then $|A|=|B|$ (this is known as the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem)). So instead of a bijection, we could give two injections as well.

Comment: Thanks. Pointing out that cardinality is defined in terms of function mappings is a great point, as well as the extra viewpoint of taking two injective functions instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: If we were unable to find a function that relates these two sets
>   bijectively, then does it follow that the proposition must be false?

A: No, it doesn't. If you cannot find a function it doesn't mean there are no such functions. Maybe they're just too difficult to find.

> Q: Is there more than one possible way to create a bijective function within a proof?

Absolutely, if sets $A$ and $B$ are both of cardinality say $n$, then there are $n!$ bijective functions that you can use for the proof by bijection.

> Q: Is the creation of the function that maps A to B (whether it be bijective, injective or surjective depending on what you are proving) that is really the key to the proof?

If you are using bijections in your proof then you must use bijective mappings in general.
The key is finding another set:

1. that you can find a *bijection* with (not injections or surjection)
2. that is easily countable

If you find a trivial bijection between the set in question and another set, then it might not be easy to enumerate the second set which is eventually of no use.

> Q: In general, are there instances were two seemingly unrelated sets can be connected by the creation of some mapping function and then used to prove some proposition?

Unrelated sets can be mapped to each other bijectively only if they are of same cardinality. Even then, finding a useful mapping might not be trivial.

Comment: What do you mean with "easily countable"? Cardinality naturally extends to uncountable sets as well. Furthermore, finding injections or (assuming Axiom of Choice) surjections is also a valid way to prove equal cardinality by [this theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem), so what do you mean with "not injections or surjection"?

Comment: This thread is about finite countable sets. In their third question, the thread owner is talking about functions from $A$ to $B$ that can injective, surjective or bijective. In the context of finite countable sets, only *bijective* functions are useful for proving equal cardinality between two sets which is another way of saying injective functions exists from $A$ to $B$ and $B$ to $A$. Aso, easily countable means that the bijective mapping we use for the combinatorial proof should result in a set that is easier to count than the original set.

Comment: I don't see it mentioned anywhere that this thread is about finite sets. Neither do I see how "easiness" of counting is relevant (or how it would be defined).

Comment: You are right, the OP didn't mention finite countable sets directly but it was implied by the example they provided. The "easiness" of counting, for bijective proofs, is only relevant when the original set of objects cannot be counted easily. The example shown by the poster is  good illustration of this: set $A$ can not be readily counted but for the cardinality of set $B$ we have a formula i.e., counting the number of elements of set $B$  is easier which is the whole point of the question. And since there is a bijection between the two sets, we know the cardinality of set $A$ through $B$.